# Controlling who pushes to my github repository

Tags: github, repository, organization

I setup an organization repository for a code that several of us are working on.  Currently, I only added one other owner of the repository.  It has no other members.  I want to make it so that nobody but the owners or members can push to the repository.  When I had a repository in my individual account, I had to add an ssh key in order to push to the repository; however, I did not have to do this to push to the organization repository.  How can I be sure that nobody else can push to the repo?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, push access to the repository is controlled through the individual account.  I noticed that my SSH key is still in my individual account.  When I push to the ssh link to the repo that is provided on the github repository page, the SSH key in my individual account is used.  Someone who is not a member of the repository would not have push access.  I was told by github support that trying to push through the http link would prompt the user for their github user ID and password.